# parse through JSON Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
Test.Customers = [{
    "CustomerPortals":[{
        "filename":"chrysanthemum.jpg",
        "ext":"jpg",
        },{
        "name":"Lighthouse.jpg",
        "filename":"lighthouse.jpg",
        "ext":"jpg",
        },{
        "filename":"lighthouse.jpg",
        "ext":"jpg",
        }
        }]
```

I have this json stored in my DOM. Sometimes there will be 0 items and sometimes multiple items in CustomerPortals array. But I want to parse through them and show the filename. Does jquery make it any simpler to do that?

**EDIT**

**EDIT**

```
var Test = {};

Test.Customers = [{"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"1","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"11","test":"4251","portalname":"tye.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"12","test":"4251","portalname":"Lsdf.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"13","test":"4251","portalname":"nick.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"2","customer":"1952","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"14","test":"4252","portalname":"Chrysanthemum2.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"15","test":"4255","portalname":"navagin.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"16","test":"4257","portalname":"jasoria.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"3","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"17","test":"4231","portalname":"Zsryanmum1.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"18","test":"4651","portalname":"Ltd1.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"19","test":"4281","portalname":"ser1.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    }
                ]
```

> I want to get the portalname for all
>   the customers. the above was not
>   showing sub arrays thanks

Comment: [That isn't JSON, that's just a JavaScript object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) It's already parsed. What do you want to do with the filenames once you get them out of the object?

Comment: I noticed that your example code was missing a ] for the "CustomerPortals".

Comment: I updated my answer showing the new code using your updated example code. When I tried to use your example code as is, I got errors in Firebug. I made an educated guess as to how to fix the errors if I was wrong let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that jquery can help you with is the `.each()` function. Here is an example where I go through each filename in each customer.

**Updated code to include Portals which holds the CustomerPortals. Let me know if I interpreted your comment incorrectly.**

**Updated code again to use the new example code. The example code was causing errors so I added { } around "Portals" and its value. If that wasn't the intended format for the code let me know.**

```
var Test = {};

Test.Customers = [{"CustomerItems":
                            {"Portals":
                                {"id":"1","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                                "CustomPortals":
                                            [
                                            {"id":"11","test":"4251","portalname":"tye.jpg"},
                                             {"id":"12","test":"4251","portalname":"Lsdf.jpg"},
                                             {"id":"13","test":"4251","portalname":"nick.jpg"}
                                             ]
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            {"Portals":
                                {"id":"2","customer":"1952","resident":"yes",
                                "CustomPortals":
                                            [
                                            {"id":"14","test":"4252","portalname":"Chrysanthemum2.jpg"},
                                             {"id":"15","test":"4255","portalname":"navagin.jpg"},
                                             {"id":"16","test":"4257","portalname":"jasoria.jpg"}
                                             ]
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            {"Portals":
                                {"id":"3","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                                "CustomPortals":
                                            [
                                            {"id":"17","test":"4231","portalname":"Zsryanmum1.jpg"},
                                             {"id":"18","test":"4651","portalname":"Ltd1.jpg"},
                                             {"id":"19","test":"4281","portalname":"ser1.jpg"}
                                             ]
                                }
                            }
                    }
                ]




$(document).ready(function() {

    //Go through each customer
    $.each(Test.Customers, function(customerIndex, customerValue) {

        //Go through each CustomerPortal and display filename
        $.each(customerValue.CustomerItems.Portals.CustomPortals, function(custPortIndex, custPortValue) {

            alert('File ' + custPortValue.portalname + ' in customer ' + customerIndex);

        });

    });

});
```

**EDIT**

```
var Test = {};

Test.Customers = [{"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"1","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"11","test":"4251","portalname":"tye.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"12","test":"4251","portalname":"Lsdf.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"13","test":"4251","portalname":"nick.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"2","customer":"1952","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"14","test":"4252","portalname":"Chrysanthemum2.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"15","test":"4255","portalname":"navagin.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"16","test":"4257","portalname":"jasoria.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"3","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"17","test":"4231","portalname":"Zsryanmum1.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"18","test":"4651","portalname":"Ltd1.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"19","test":"4281","portalname":"ser1.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    }
                ]
```

> I want to get the portalname for all
>   the customers. the above was not
>   showing sub arrays thanks

Comment: actually there is another foreach loop needed as the customersportal is the sub array of Portals... how would I do that.

Comment: Is it a subarray or property of "Portals"? If possible could you update your example code in your question, so I can be certain we are on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. JSON object hierarchies aren't visible as DOM nodes.

You could use a map function, which is very easy to [write](http://www.lazycoder.com/weblog/2009/08/12/a-simple-map-function-for-plain-javascript-arrays/), and readily available in libraries like [Functional JavaScript](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/). Using it is simple:

```
filenames = Test.Customers[0].CustomerPortals.map(function(cp) { return cp.filename });
```

Then do whatever you want with the array of filenames.

**EDIT:** To confirm this, I ran the following code in a [JavaScript test bench](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/javascript/jstest5.html).

```
Test = {};

Test.Customers = [{
    "CustomerPortals":[{
        "filename":"chrysanthemum.jpg",
        "ext":"jpg",
        },{
        "name":"Lighthouse.jpg",
        "filename":"lighthouse.jpg",
        "ext":"jpg",
        },{
        "filename":"lighthouse.jpg",
        "ext":"jpg",
        }]
        }];

Array.prototype.map = function(fn) {
              var r = [];
              var l = this.length;
              for(i=0;i<l;i++)
              {
                  r.push(fn(this[i]));
              }
              return r; 
            };

alert(Test.Customers[0].CustomerPortals.map(function(cp) { return cp.filename }));
```

It displayed an alert with the following message:

> chrysanthemum.jpg,lighthouse.jpg,lighthouse.jpg

Comment: @Autolycus: It does work. I amended the question to show how.